# Datalist: Get a text value (Entered) wasn't in list

Tags: javascript

Please advise. Your help would be greatly appreciated.
I have a datalist provided, I need to get and display a text value when a user selected or entered.

For sample code below: when user selected any country, it works fine.
But I need to handle when a user enter a country that is NOT in the list (for example: "Canada"), I need to display: "Canada" is not in the country list yet.

```
<body>      
Please Select Country: 
<input type="text" list="countries" name="countryName" id="countryId" />      
<datalist id="countries">      
    <option value="India">India</option>      
    <option value="United States"></option>      
    <option value="United Kingdom"></option>      
    <option value="China"></option>      
    <option value="Nepal"></option>      
    <option value="Afghanistan"></option>      
    <option value="Iceland"></option>      
    <option value="Indonesia"></option>      
    <option value="Iraq"></option>      
    <option value="Ireland"></option>      
    <option value="Israel"></option>      
    <option value="Italy"></option>      
    <option value="Poland"></option>      
</datalist>      
</body>
```

I have tried (a code below) to enter a value not in the list (e.g: Canada), it always empty when display:

```
$("#countryId").on("change", function () {
    //var result = $(this).val();
    var country = document.getElementById('countryId').value
    alert( country + " is not in the country list yet." );
}});
```

Thank you very much in advantage.

Comment: First of all `document.getElementById('countryId').value` and `document.getElementsByName("countryName").value` are referring to the same element; and the latter returns a Nodelist. You would need to indicate the index of the item you're referring to, such as `document.getElementsByName("countryName")[0].value`. Next, don't have a `value2` defined. Finally, you don't appear to be checking to see whether the value input is in the list.

Comment: You didn't address the rest of the items my comment.

Comment: Hello, I edited the code. The document.getElementsById("countryId")[0].value didn't work.  And to check whether the value input is in the list...that where I got stuck... Thank you again

Comment: What does your console say? `document.getElementsById()` isn't a valid method. Please read through the documentation.

Comment: Hi there, I retired and  the document.getElementById('countryId').value actually was working!! I got the text input (not in the datalist) is displayed !.... I didn't know what I missed before..... but it works now. Thank you so much for trying to help. Have a great day

Comment: Except, as is, your code doesn't even check the value against the list. It just returns whatever is input, regardless of whether it's in the datalist.

Answer (score 0):

I retried and  the `document.getElementById('countryId').value` actually was working!!
 I got the text input (not in the datalist) displayed !.... I didn't know what I missed before..... but it works now.